# TKINTER: TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: string, tkinter, bucle-for

estoy haciendo un spam bot en tkinter, le digo que quiero spamear, el tiempo que pase entre cada mensaje que se mande, y cuantas veces lo va a enviar, pero ahi esta el problema, estoy usando un FOR pero me dice el error del titulo

Este es el codigo:

```
from tkinter import *
import pyautogui
import time

def spam():
    spam_text = mensaje.get()
    _tiempo = str(tiempo.get())
    _cantidad = str(cantidad.get())

    time.sleep(3)
    for i in range(_cantidad):
        pyautogui.typewrite(spam_text)
        pyautogui.press("enter")
        time.sleep(_tiempo)

raiz = Tk()
raiz.geometry("500x345")
raiz.title("Spam Bot")
raiz.resizable(False, False)

titulo = Label(raiz, text = "Spam Bot", font = ("", 14, "bold")).place(x=200,y=0)

label_mensaje = Label(raiz, text = "Introduce el texto que se va a spamear:", font = ("", 13)).place(x=0,y=50)
mensaje = StringVar()
entry_mensaje = Entry(raiz, textvariable = mensaje, font = ("", 11)).place(x=290,y=50)

label_tiempo = Label(raiz, text = "Introduce el tiempo:", font = ("", 13)).place(x=0,y=90)
tiempo = StringVar()
entry_tiempo = Entry(raiz, font = ("", 11)).place(x=155,y=90)

label_cantidad = Label(raiz, text = "Introduce la cantidad de mensajes:", font = ("", 13)).place(x=0,y=130)
cantidad = StringVar()
entry_cantidad = Entry(raiz, font = ("", 11)).place(x=260,y=130)

label_test = Label(raiz, text = "El tiempo es cuanto se tardará entre cada mensaje, por ejemplo: se manda", font = ("", 11)).place(x=0,y=180)
label_test2 = Label(raiz, text = "un mensaje y pasan X segundos y se manda otra vez, etc...", font = ("", 11)).place(x=0,y=200)

label_warning = Label(raiz, text = "Advertencia! Al presionar el boton, pasaran 3 segundos para que puedas", font = ("", 11)).place(x=0,y=240)
label_warning2 = Label(raiz, text = "irte a donde quieras spamear el texto...", font = ("", 11)).place(x=0,y=260)

spamear = Button(raiz, text = "Spamear Texto!", font = ("", 13, "bold"), command = spam).place(x=170,y=295)

raiz.mainloop()
```

se que para convertir un entero a un string se necesita la funcion str() pero para el for no me funciona, por ejemplo quiero enviar el mensaje 40 veces, me da el error, no se si le tengo que añadir algo o usar algo que no sea el for(si es el caso me dicen k puedo usar porfavor ...)

Este es el error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mi usuario :v\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/mi usuario :v/OneDrive/Bibliotecas/Python/Archivos py/SpamBot.py", line 11, in spam
    for i in range(_cantidad):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: justo el mensaje te lo dice, el método range() se utiliza con enteros no con cadenas un ejemplo de range es for x in range(10) print(x). En este caso podés recorrer directamente la cadena: for i in cantidad: etc.

Comment: por eso, en el cuadro para obtener la cantidad de spams que quiero mandar, le pongo un numero y me da un erro, y lo de quitar el range no me funciona

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!

El problema reside en que `range` funciona con `int` no con `str`, en este caso lo que podrías hacer es pasarle al bucle directamente la variable `__cantidad`.

Algo así:

```
def spam():
    spam_text = mensaje.get()
    _tiempo = str(tiempo.get())
    _cantidad = int(cantidad.get())

    time.sleep(3)
    for i in _cantidad:
        pyautogui.typewrite(spam_text)
        pyautogui.press("enter")
        time.sleep(_tiempo)
```

Convertí en `int` lo que obtenías de cantidad pero la verdad no se que tan bien implementado esta o si solo funcionaria pasándole directamente cantidad al bucle.

Tampoco estoy seguro si con pasarle el `int` el bucle se repite el numero de veces del entero, pero eso es porque todavía no entiendo muy bien de bucles.

Espero te sea de utilidad.

P.D. solo como sugerencia, he leído por muchas partes que usar `import tkinter as *` es una mala practica, se recomiendo importarlo como tk.

`import tkinter as tk`

---

¡Hola! Realice una modificación quitando el `int` e hice una prueba en Repl.it y no me arrojo ningún error, te pongo el código modificado.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

def spam():
    spam_text = mensaje.get()
    _tiempo = str(tiempo.get())
    _cantidad = cantidad.get()

    time.sleep(3)
    for i in _cantidad:
        pyautogui.typewrite(spam_text)
        pyautogui.press("enter")
        time.sleep(_tiempo)

raiz = tk.Tk()
raiz.geometry("500x345")
raiz.title("Spam Bot")
raiz.resizable(False, False)

titulo = tk.Label(raiz, text = "Spam Bot", font = ("", 14, "bold")).place(x=200,y=0)

label_mensaje = tk.Label(raiz, text = "Introduce el texto que se va a spamear:", font = ("", 13)).place(x=0,y=50)
mensaje = tk.StringVar()
entry_mensaje = tk.Entry(raiz, textvariable = mensaje, font = ("", 11)).place(x=290,y=50)

label_tiempo = tk.Label(raiz, text = "Introduce el tiempo:", font = ("", 13)).place(x=0,y=90)
tiempo = tk.StringVar()
entry_tiempo = tk.Entry(raiz, font = ("", 11)).place(x=155,y=90)

label_cantidad = tk.Label(raiz, text = "Introduce la cantidad de mensajes:", font = ("", 13)).place(x=0,y=130)
cantidad = tk.StringVar()
entry_cantidad = tk.Entry(raiz, font = ("", 11)).place(x=260,y=130)

label_test = tk.Label(raiz, text = "El tiempo es cuanto se tardará entre cada mensaje, por ejemplo: se manda", font = ("", 11)).place(x=0,y=180)
label_test2 = tk.Label(raiz, text = "un mensaje y pasan X segundos y se manda otra vez, etc...", font = ("", 11)).place(x=0,y=200)

label_warning = tk.Label(raiz, text = "Advertencia! Al presionar el boton, pasaran 3 segundos para que puedas", font = ("", 11)).place(x=0,y=240)
label_warning2 = tk.Label(raiz, text = "irte a donde quieras spamear el texto...", font = ("", 11)).place(x=0,y=260)

spamear = tk.Button(raiz, text = "Spamear Texto!", font = ("", 13, "bold"), command = spam).place(x=170,y=295)

raiz.mainloop()
```

Espero esta vez si sea de ayuda:)

Comment: borre lo de importarlo y puse import tkinter as tk y ahora icluso la primera linea de codigo no funciona :b (raiz = Tk()) NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined

Comment: PD: no funciona :/ me dice : TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: @AlanRichterv acabo de modificar la respuesta a ver si te sirve:)